# Express.js HTTP 500 ERROR: Page works with res.send("Some text"); but does error caused when using res.render('file');

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, server

I have a page with route */request* that contains a form. The form method is POST and the action is */request*. What is supposed to happen in the POST handler in *request.js* is to do something with the form data (store in DB etc.) and then redirect to a different page with route */trips*.

The GET handler works fine whenever I use res.send("Some text here"); but gives me an HTTP 500 Internal server error when I try to render a page using res.render('trips') for example.

**Here's the code for request.js:**

```
var router = require('express').Router();


router.get('/', checkLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('request', {
        user: req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});

router.post('/', checkLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); //data should be stored in DB
    res.redirect('/trips'); //Should redirect to /trips after form 
submission. Why ERROR 500?
});

function checkLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    //Redirect to home if not logged in
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = router;
```

**Here's the code for trips.js:**

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', checkLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.send("This is the trips route GET response!");
});
```

So the **above part works** and prints *"This is the trips route GET response!"* when I access localhost:8000/trips (from the navbar or by submitting the form)

```
router.get('/', checkLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('trips');
});
```

However, when I write this instead it gives me a **HTTP ERROR 500** localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

```
function checkLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    //Redirect to home if not logged in
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = router;
```

Here's my **trips.ejs** file (for context):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<title><%= user.firstName %>'s Trips - Erkab</title>-->

    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/erkab.css">


    <script src="/public/js/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="top" style="width: 100%">

<% include templates/header.ejs %>

<% if (userType != "Rider") {
    userType = "Driver";
} %>

<div id="changeableView" class="container-fluid">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>USER TYPE</th>
            <th>LOCATION</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>TIME</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><%= userType %></td>
            <td><%= points %> - <%= area %></td>
            <td><%= date %></td>
            <td><%= time %></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="/public/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you see logged in the Node console? It might be something as simple as the EJS file is trying to use variables that you aren't passing in. You could try changing the contents of that file to something like 'Hello' to see if that renders successfully. If not, perhaps you could post the code you've used to configure the settings `views` and `view engine` so we can double check you've got those set correctly?

Comment: You seem to have asked the same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486074/express-js-localhost-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-request-http-error-500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the relevant information for this question is included in the other copy you posted:

[Express.js: localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 (GET Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486074/express-js-localhost-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-request-http-error-500)

I would suggest changing the code you've posted here to this:

```
router.get('/', checkLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('trips', {
        user: req.user,
        userType: 'Driver',
        area: null,
        points: null,
        date: null,
        time: null,
        driverPref: null,
    });
});
```

I don't think you'll need all of that but you can tidy up once it renders.

I suspect there are two real problems here. One is this line:

```
<!--<title><%= user.firstName %>'s Trips - Erkab</title>-->
```

That 'comment' won't prevent EJS from trying to access `user.firstName`. The comment is just part of the output string as far as EJS is concerned and won't be treated as anything special.

There's also this:

```
<% if (userType != "Rider") {
```

I believe that will also be failing as `userType` won't be declared.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @skirtle. It was indeed the unpassed variables used in the EJS file that caused the error. I thought that the page should render fine with null values for example but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

`res.render` are used to render static templates files  using some template engine like mustache, jade etc..

So you should configure the template engine, create a static file and then res.render('trips') interprets and renders the template.

You can find informations on how to use template engines in express [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: Well this is obvious. I've already done that. In my case it's supposed to render an **.ejs** file.

Comment: How are the views configured? And what is the directory structure?

Comment: They're all in the _views directory_

Comment: Probably another obvious thing... Do you have `module.exports = router;` at the end of trips.js? Beside that I made a quick test locally removing the checkLoggedIn function and passing mock data to the view and everything seems to work for me.

Comment: Yeah it does have `module.exports = router;` at the end. That's what's really making me frustrated. It is supposed to work as all the other pages I have work fine! Thanks anyway Filippo.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [this tutorial](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) to catch your error:

> In this example, the generic logErrors might write request and error information to stderr, for example:

```
function logErrors (err, req, res, next) {   console.error(err.stack)  next(err) }
```

Alternatively, you can use the `try-catch` statement. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that really answers the question

Comment: I'm not really looking for error handling. I'm interested in knowing WHY the error is caused and how to solve it.

Comment: I see, then you can use the `try-catch` to find out what exactly kind of error you're getting.

Comment: @Azuloo I've stated _clearly_ that its an HTTP 500 Internal server error.

Comment: @HeshamSaleh Yes, I understood it after reading your post but under the  _kind_ of error I didn't mean the HTTP status code, I meant the body of the error.